# how to create a check condition for the Data grid view having first column(integer identity enabled in DB)?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a data grid view where the first column is "ID" which is an integer identity column and that is been made as read only mode in the grid view.

I made the enable adding option checked for grid view such that the user can add any new rows.

problem:
when the user adds new rows they wont be able to add the "ID" column value since its a read only mode and identity enabled.

The user selects each row in the grid view and clicks the "Update or ADD" button to add new records to the database.

I need to create a check condition where for the selected row the first column value"ID" should be 'NULL' or zero.(such that i can do add operation instead of update in the same button)

I have the below code which retrieves the last or max "ID" column value for the selected row (new added row). But it should return only "NULL" or zero value since for the new added rows the user cant enter any "ID column value"

```
 if (dataGridView.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedrowindex = dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                if (selectedrowindex == 0)
                 {
                  //insert operation    
                  }
               }
```

Is it possible to create the check condition for this one ? let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you need. You want the value of the cell "ID" in the new added row by the user to automatically be set to "0"? Then you might want to handle the `UserAddedRow` event and set the value in the column programmatically.

Comment: question is not clear